# Simplification problem with discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I am trying to achieve this equation:

$$x_1x_4 \lor x_1x_2x_3\lor (¬x_1)x_3(¬x_4)$$

I start with:

$$(x_1 \lor (¬x_4))(x_3\lor x_4)((¬x_1)\lor x_2\lor x_4)$$

Then I do simplify in the following stages:

$$(x_1x_3\lor x_1x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3 \lor (¬x_4)x_4)((¬x_1)\lor x_2 \lor x_4)$$

$$(x_1x_3(¬x_1)\lor x_1x_3x_2 \lor x_1x_3x_4 \lor x_1x_4(¬x_1) \lor x_1x_4x_2\lor x_1x_4x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3(¬x_1)\lor (¬x_4)x_3x_2 \lor (¬x_4)x_3x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_4(¬x_1)\lor (¬x_4)x_4x_2\lor (¬x_4)x_4x_4)$$

$$x_1x_3x_2\lor x_1x_3x_4\lor x_1x_4x_2\lor x_1x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3(¬x_1)\lor (¬x_4)x_3x_2$$

$$x_1x_3x_2\lor x_1x_3x_4\lor x_1x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3(¬x_1)\lor (¬x_4)x_3x_2$$

$$x_1x_3x_2\lor x_1x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3(¬x_1)\lor (¬x_4)x_3x_2$$

However, I am unsure how to proceed from the last line.

Please help me!

I'm in a hurry :(

Comment: I've edited your post slightly so it is more readable (added LaTeX and changed some grammar), but you should make sure it is what you mean still.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_1x_3x_2\lor x_1x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3(¬x_1)\lor (¬x_4)x_3x_2$$

$$x_1x_3x_2\lor x_1x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3(¬x_1)\lor (¬x_4)x_3x_2x_1\lor (¬x_4)x_3x_2(¬x_1)$$

$$x_1x_3x_2\lor x_1x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3(¬x_1)\lor (¬x_4)x_3x_2x_1$$

$$x_1x_3x_2\lor x_1x_4\lor (¬x_4)x_3(¬x_1)$$